# Remove duplicate value inside the arraylist from a dynamically created layout Android

Tags: android, dynamic, arraylist, android-framelayout, viewgroup

I have created a dynamic add/removable UI where the user will enter an item's cost in a edit text, and when the user click add. The value will be saved in an ArrayList and at the same time a text view will be added with the same value in there. When the user click remove, the value will be removed from the ArrayList, and the text view will be removed as well.

So it works just the way I wanted had the user enter something like [1.00 2.00 3.00 4.00 5.00 6.00].

However if the user enter something with a duplicate value like [1.00 2.00 3.00 2.00 4.00 2.00].

If remove was clicked on one of the text view with value "2.00", then sometimes the incorrect index with "2.00" will be removed, and the sequence inside my ArrayList becomes out of sync with my text view.

I've been trying several approaches for the past 2 weeks, but just couldn't get it right. If you guys can help me out?

Below is my implementation:

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rowLinearLayoutItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:baselineAligned="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/rowButtonRemove"
            android:text="-"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_button"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rowItemCost"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rowItemTotal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment.java

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.advButtonAddItem:
                String itemAddString = editBoxItemAdd.getText().toString();
                if (itemAddString.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please Enter Item Cost", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
                    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                    final TextView rowItemTotal = (TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.rowItemTotal);

                    Button rowButtonRemove = (Button) addView.findViewById(R.id.rowButtonRemove);

                    rowItemTotal.setText(editBoxItemAdd.getText().toString());

                    itemList.add(rowItemTotal.getText().toString());  

                    updateCost();

                    rowButtonRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            ((LinearLayout)addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);
                            itemList.remove(rowItemTotal.getText().toString()); //Remove inputted Item Cost into ArrayList itemList

                            updateCost();
                        }
                    });
                    row.addView(addView);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should consider adding a second array list or implement all this in a map and there you can keep track of their indexes too! Do you want to just remove the duplicates or handle what happens when there is a duplicate value with multiple indexes in your list?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That gives me an idea to store my value in a hashmap instead of ArrayList. I added a "Log.d("LOG","v " + v);" inside my rowButtonRemove.setOnClickListener, and the logcat generated below. 

v android.widget.Button{42323740 VFED..C. ...P.... 0,2-70,72 #7f0a0080 app:id/rowButtonRemove}

I think the value "42323740" would be perfect for me to use as my hashmap's key, but I can't seem to figure out how to take that value out into a variable. Do you know of a way how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
((LinearLayout)addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);
```

it will always delets the previously added item

because addview is the lastitem you used

so change it to

```
((LinearLayout)addView.getParent()).removeView(v);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It doesn't do quite that I wanted because the layout now doesn't get removed. However it gives me an idea using the unique value in "v" as my hashmap's key. I added a "Log.d("LOG","v " + v);" inside my rowButtonRemove.setOnClickListener, and the logcat generated below. 

v android.widget.Button{42323740 VFED..C. ...P.... 0,2-70,72 #7f0a0080 app:id/rowButtonRemove}

I think the value "42323740" would be perfect for me to use as my hashmap's key, but I can't seem to figure out how to take that value out into a variable. Do you know of a way how I can do this?

Comment: if you want a unqiue thing you can use v.getId()